# Understanding the Fourier Transform of tempered test functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

The test function space is defined by $\mathscr{T} = \mathscr{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to be all functions of the class $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which decreases as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, together with all their derivatives, faster than any power of $|x|^{-1}$.

Continuity in $\mathscr{T}$ is defined by saying that the sequence $\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}, \ldots , $ belonging to $\mathscr{T}$ converges to the function $\phi \in \mathscr{T}$, $\phi_{k} \rightarrow \phi$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ in $\mathscr{T}$, if for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$

$$x^{\beta} D^{\alpha}\phi_{k}(x) \implies x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}\phi(x), \quad k \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$$

Since the test functions belonging to $\mathscr{T}$ are absolutely integrable over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we define the operation of the Fourier transform $F$ over them by

$$F[\phi](\xi) := \int \phi(x)e^{i(\xi, x)} dx, \quad \phi \in \mathscr{T}.$$

I do not understand what the notation in the exponent means i.e. $i(\xi, x)$. I am unsure whether I forgot something trivial about notations?

Comment: It's the inner product of the two vectors

Comment: So $i(\xi, x) = \langle \xi , x \rangle$ and the $i$ is the inner product and not the imaginary unit $i$?

Comment: No $i$ is still the imaginary unit

Comment: So imaginary unit $i$ multiplied with the inner product of $\xi$ and $x$. Thanks. Been confused by this unnecessarily.

Comment: In dimension 1 it is $e^{i \xi_1 x_1}$ in  dimension 2 it is $e^{i (\xi_1 x_1+\xi_2x_2)}$ which is the same as doing the Fourier transform of the functions of $x_1$ then of the obtained functions of $x_2$.

Comment: @reuns yes, the inner product is the coordinates multiplied by one another and then summed. I was just confused by the bracket notation for the inner product since I am accustomed to using $\langle, \rangle$.

Comment: Since the vector space is $\mathbb R^n$ it would have been natural to write $e^{i\xi\cdot x}$ instead.